# Generated codes of protobuf are different between two mac

Tags: protocol-buffers

I'm using two mac. The results of compiling of protobuf are not the same. I have no idea.
Please help me.

```
docker run --rm -v$PWD:$PWD -w $PWD thethingsindustries/protoc \
  --java_out=$PWD/java \
  -I:${PWD} \
  --grpc-java_out=$PWD/java \
  mypath/*.proto
```

For example,

[image]

[image]

Both uses 3.15.5 version protobuf installed by brew.

Comment: and if you use `protoc --version`, does it say the same thing on both? (presumably "libprotoc 3.15.5")

Comment: @MarcGravell Yes. It says 3.15.5 on both.